# Obtaining an integral over a sphere from an integral in Euclidean space

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $f \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ and $\varphi \in C^\infty (\mathbb{R}^{2n})$. Suppose I know how to calculate the integral

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2n}}f\bigg(\frac{|x|^2 + |y|^2}{2}\bigg) \varphi(x,y) \ dxdy$$

for any choice of $f \in C_c^\infty (\mathbb{R})$ how would I be able to derive the value of
$$\int_{S^{2n-1}}\varphi  \ d\lambda$$
Where $d\lambda$ is the usual sphere measure obtained from Lebesgue measure.

This arises in the context where my first integral can be determined from spectral data of an operator and I want to say something about the integral of $\varphi$ over a sphere. I know that if I wrote the first integral in polar coordinates I would get

$$\int_{S^{2d-1}} \int_0 ^\infty f\big(\frac{r^2}{2}\big) \varphi(r \lambda)r^{2d-1}dr d\lambda$$
If $\varphi$ were independent of $r$ then I would be done since I could just pick a nice $f$ to compute the $r$ integral but otherwise I'm not sure. I think I'm just forgetting my basic analysis.

Comment: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope. Please [avoid "I have no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933). Defining keywords and trying a simpler, similar problem often helps.

Comment: I wrote an answer, but due to the lack of context, I deleted it. If context is added, I will undelete it.

Comment: @robjohn Apologies, I added some more detail.

Comment: Thanks for responding to the request to improve the question. I have undeleted my answer. I hope it is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\eta(t)=\frac{\exp\left(\frac1{t^2-1}\right)\,\left[t^2\lt1\right]}{\int_{-1}^1\exp\left(\frac1{t^2-1}\right)\,\mathrm{d}t}$ be a unit mass bump function supported where $|t|\le1$.

Define $f_k(t)=\frac{2k\eta(k(2t-1))}{(2t)^{n-1}}$, then $f_k(t)$ is supported where $\left|t-\frac12\right|\le\frac1{2k}$.

Furthermore,
$$
\int_0^\infty f_k(t)\,t^{n-1}\,\mathrm{d}t=\frac1{2^{n-1}}
$$
and
$$
\omega_{2n-1}\int_0^\infty f_k\!\left(\tfrac{r^2}2\right)r^{2n-1}\,\mathrm{d}r=\omega_{2n-1}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2n}}f_k\!\left(\tfrac{|x|^2+|y|^2}2\right)\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y=\omega_{2n-1}
$$
and since $f_k\!\left(\frac{|x|^2+|y|^2}2\right)$ is a radial function, supported where $\left|\,|x|^2+|y|^2-1\,\right|\le\frac1k$, we get that
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2n}}f_k\!\left(\tfrac{|x|^2+|y|^2}2\right)\varphi(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y=\int_{S^{2n-1}}\varphi(\lambda)\,\mathrm{d}\lambda
$$

Comment: Ah, one question about your last line. In the limit, $f_k$ becomes a function supported on the sphere, a measure zero set of $R^{2n}$ so how is it the case that the RHS arises as the limit of the LHS?

Comment: The integral of each $f_k\!\left(\frac{|x|^2+|y|^2}2\right)$ over $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ is $\omega_{2n-1}$, the surface area of the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$. $f_k\!\left(\frac{|x|^2+|y|^2}2\right)$ is constant over each spherical shell. $f_k\!\left(\frac{|x|^2+|y|^2}2\right)$ is supported on the "shell" $\left|\,r^2-1\,\right|=\left|\,|x|^2+|y|^2-1\,\right|\le\frac1k$. So the function is supported over thinner and thinner shells surrounding the unit sphere.

Comment: Ahh, the last line is the approximation of the Dirac Delta by compactly smooth functions.

Comment: @MemeboyInc.: Indeed; just spread out evenly over the unit sphere.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [hyperspherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates) and that $f(\cdots)$ depends only of the radius ($\sqrt{|x|^2 + |y|^2}$).
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2n}}f\bigg(\frac{|x|^2 + |y|^2}{2}\bigg)\varphi(x,y)\,dxdy$$
will be a product of a 1D integral that depends only of $f$ and $\int_{S^{2n-1}}\varphi\,d\lambda$.

Also relevant: the [coarea formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coarea_formula).

Comment: Ah, why is it impossible to compute the second integral if I know how to compute the first for fixed $\varphi$ and every possible choice of compactly supported $f$. Can I not choose a judicious sequence of $f$ that makes it possible?

Comment: @MemeboyInc., I've misread your question. See the edit.

Comment: Dumb question, In polar coordinates the above integral would be $\int_0^\infty \int_{S^{2n-1}}  f(\frac{r^2}{2}) \varphi( r \omega) r^{2n-1} dr d\omega$. Since $\varphi$ also depends on $r$ why could I just multiply the 2 integrals?

Comment: @MemeboyInc., you can extract the $f(r^2/2)$ from $\int_{S^{2n-1}}$.